# Regression when one class occurs for middle values of a predictor

Tags: r, regression, binary-data

I am trying to model a process with a binary response (pass/fail).  The process fails if the predictor is large or small, but in the middle it passes.  The result looks something like this:

[image]

I want to fit a model to this data.  I have tried logistic regression, which doesn't yield good results:

[image]

I'm thinking there must be an obvious way to model this type of data but I haven't come across anything yet.  Looking for advice on what modelling approach should be taken with data like this.  And is it able to be generalized for multiple predictors.

Comment: add a quadratic term for the predictor variable...

Comment: I wouldn't call it  a "bell curve"...

Comment: Not a "bell curve" but I didn't know how else to describe it in the title

Comment: Could you provide some insight about what happens behind the scenes when I add I quadratic term to the predictor variable?  I can see that it works in this case, but not really sure how.

Answer (score 6):

Solution based on General Abrial's comment.

Here's a model that fits the data.  Using R:

```
N <- 200
noise <- rnorm(N, sd=5)
pred <- floor(runif(N, min=10, max=80))
result <- factor(ifelse(dv50 + noise < 30,0,
                    ifelse(dv50 + noise > 60,0,1)))

data <- data.frame(pred, result)

lmfit <- glm(result ~ poly(pred,2), family=binomial, data=data)

test <- data.frame(pred=10:80)

test$predict <- predict(lmfit, newdata=test, type="response")
```

The key step being adding a quadratic term by changing the formula in `glm` from `result ~ pred` to `result ~ poly(pred,2)`.  The result of the model:

[image]

Comment: This solution works because in logit space, the predictor is higher near 40 and lower at the extremes, i.e. it's a parabola open down. To see what I mean, plot change `type='link'` in your predict call.